# pointer-events: none if cart is empty

Tags: pointer-events

first, sorry my bad English.
i use Elementor pro + WooCommerce in my website.
for cart, i use Elementor menu cart in my website and set that on header.
you can see that [in this link](https://vatantajhiz.com/).
i try to make a way; if cart is empty, pointer-events: none effect on that and cart basket unclickable.
and if item added in cart, pointer-events: none code remove from basket.
is any snippet code for that?
thanks.

pointer-events: none code